# Auto Image resize with broswer window using img max-width: 100% works in Chrome but not IE when parent div has position: absolute

Tags: image, internet-explorer, css, google-chrome, firefox

I am building a responsive web site and I am finding that Auto Image resize with broswer window resize using img max-width:100% works in Chrome but not IE and Firefox when any parent or ancestor  has position:absolute;

(For information about this technique see 
        http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries
)

The following code can be used to demonstrate or reproduce this problem. you can also see this at http://sketchmotion.com/image-test2/.  You will notice that resizing the browser window will resize the image in Chrome but not IE   (I am running IE 11) .  However,  if you remove the following lines:

```
    .mydiv{
        position: absolute;  
    }
```

You will find that it now works in both Chrome AND IE.

This is not helpful since I I use position: absolute;  on some of my parent divs on my site.  And I need my site to work in IE and Firefox.

Please let me know if there is a work around for this problem so I can get the images to resize with the browser window on my site.

```
<html>
<head>

    <!--  <link href="/cssh/ImageTest.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"></link>  -->

    <style type="text/css">

        .mydiv{
            position: absolute;  
        }

        img{
        /***  Scaling Images with the Browser Window in CSS is pretty simple to implement for both images and video.  ***/
        /***  You can set the media element’s max-width to 100 percent, and the browser will make    ***/
        /***  the image shrink and expand depending on its container.    ***/
        /***  To maintain the right proportions use auto height  ***/
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto; 
        width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
        }

</style>



</head>

<body>  


<!--    -->
    <div class="mydiv"> 
    <div class="slides">    
    <div class="slide"> 
        <img alt=""    src="http://sketchmotion.com/ImagesSM/SM_Slider_1_SketchMotion_w_Sketch.jpg" />
    </div>  
    </div>    
    </div>   



</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
.mydiv {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;  
}
```

I don't have an explanation exactly why, but this works.  :)

Comment: @user3101077 Terry Clancy - if this answer solved your problem or was helpful, please accept it as the answer or up vote it please.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I confirmed that using width: 100%;  for parent and all ancestor divs makes it work in IE.  However this is a bit of a pain because often that is not what you want to do.  Chrome does not have that limitation and scales the image regardless which seems like a more sensible and consistent approach IMHO.

Thanks again  Terry Clancy

Answer (score -1):

For the responsive to work on IE. Do not include pictures in a `<table>`. Just use `<div>` and use CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9;
}
```