# Resizing a table with table-layout: auto does not work in IE/FF, ok in Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox, css-tables

I have a table with a few images and I like the auto layout: it gives me exactly the sizing I want.

My problem is that I want to scale the whole table equally, which works fine with Chrome by setting a width size. However, with Firefox or Internet Explorer, the table won't re-size and all images are displayed at 100%

```
table.quad
{
    background: #F0F0F0;
    border: 1px solid #e0e0e0;
    /*table-layout: fixed;*/
    width: 100%;
}
```

Source is here: http://jsfiddle.net/7br0prdq/

Sub-question: I would like to have the same layout without the trick I used on image 1 (this image is set as a background image of the cell, not an `<img />` like the others are)

Comment: what version of IE have you tested in?

Comment: I only have IE 11 here

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Auto Image resize with broswer window using img max-width: 100% works in Chrome but not IE when parent div has position: absolute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577491/auto-image-resize-with-broswer-window-using-img-max-width-100-works-in-chrome)

Answer (score -1):

you might have the same issue as descriped here:

[Auto Image resize with broswer window using img max-width: 100% works in Chrome but not IE when parent div has position: absolute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20577491/auto-image-resize-with-broswer-window-using-img-max-width-100-works-in-chrome)

Try using 100% width on Parent, as said in the comment.

best regards paulqq

Comment: Might be the same problem, but 100% width on parent won't help.